# Touchpad scrolling is not happening in Slackware 13?

Tags: touchpad, slackware

Although other functions are working properly..little bemused...only the scrolling not happening..

Comment: Can you share more information about at least OS, Driver and Touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to the Xorg Synaptics driver not being installed installed. X will recognize it as a pointing device without the drivers, but the scrolling, lock-on-type, and other touchpad features only work when the driver is installed.